# SQL Server parser for Azure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

We have migrated our production environment to Azure (using SQL Azure instead of SQL Server)

Our local development environment uses SQL Server.  We write **change scripts** when database changes need to occur during a release.

**PROBLEM**

The issue now is that some T-SQL commands/statements/keywords don't work when run on SQL Azure.  This is constantly disrupting our release process.

Educating everyone to use a subset of T-SQL is happening, but these problems continue to crop up.

Is it not possible for us to parse our SQL scripts as 'Azure SQL compatible' in SQL Server using the parser before running them:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the new "SQL Server Database Project", there is a feature in Visual Studio that allows you to select the "Target Platform" to SQL Azure.  This will allow you to build all your t-sql scripts and check them for SQL Azure compatibility.  Any compatibility errors will throw errors and it can create a bacdac/dacpac/t-sql script that is compatible with SQL Azure.

In order to take advantage of this, you have to manage your code using the "SQL Server Database Project" projects in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to like this answer .. but the best bet is to move your development environment to SQL Azure. We started in the same process but you will just have the constant battle. We used Redgates SQL Compare tools but I don't believe they will solve your problems, but maybe worth a shot as they are constantly getting better.

Even if you have multiple devs and they each need a SQL Database I would still recommend getting everyone to signed up with Azure and pay the cost under it. Thankfully the database are not that expensive to run, and you might get under the free tier structure.  It is still cheaper for us to run the cost of the SQL Azure Dev boxes than it is to have the pain and waste of time at release.